# Can python split a 835 file into 2 specific files?

Tags: python

I have been working on a code that would split csv file into the way i want to.the code is shown below and might need some improvement possible I would greatly appreciate it.
My question now is well can python or my code do the same with 835 files or do I need somehow to convert them to csv file first in the same code?
Any help is appreciated!
Thank you very much.

```
import csv
Payers = "Payers.csv"
PayerName = []
PayerName = file.read().split(',')
choicePayer = input("Enter the payer of your choice: ")
check = 0 


for i in storeName:
    if i == choicePayer:
        check = 1
        break



if check == 0:
print("The payer is not present in file")

else:
payerName.remove(choicePayer)

 with open('file1.csv','w') as csvfile:
 writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
 writer.writerow([choicePayer])
 with open("file2.csv","w") as csvfile:
 writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
 writer.writerow(PayerName)`
```

I would like to have the 2 files opened in csv format as output.Maybe also fixing only 1 payer to be in the first file consistently instead of having to enter the input every time might help as well.
Any help/idea would help me a lot.

Comment: You need to fix your code formatting. Identation is significant in Python and I can't tell what your code should do without proper formatting.

Comment: I am new here so I am sorry about that. what is wrong with the formatting?

Comment: The indentation is an integral part of Python. You need to add the correct indentation to the code inside the `for` loop and `if` statements.

Comment: I just edited it hopefully you understand the code better now

Comment: I've partially updated the indentation of your code. But after this point I'm not sure how much the next if statement should be indented.

Comment: I wanted to put it together with the else and that was it.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else to help me Gary Kerr and/or other people. Thank you I really appreciate it.